# How does the backend of a e-commerce looks

Tags: e-commerce

I would like to know how does e-commerce sites maintain their databases?

Let say they are selling a product name X from a marchant M
Now the merchant increases or decreases the cost of the item. It is manually edited in the e-commerse backend ? Is this part automated?

If there is an id associated with the item, is id given by the merchant or  the e-commerce site?

There can be 10 same product items provided by 10 different merchant. Now the specification of the product is same but the amount varies from each merchant. if let say every merchant change the cost of the item and tell us the cost. How can we in automated fashion edit the backend in such a situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shop owner with the website is adjusting their prices independently of the wholesaler. This can be done manually in an online product admin interface, or it can be done through some kind of data feed of all products like XML or CVS. The data feed can be coming directly from a retail point of sale system. If the wholesaler raises the prices - the shop owner still has stock on hand of the product they bought at the previous price. When the shop owner takes delivery of the new stock and enters that inventory into the system - at that point they would adjust the prices.

A product has a UPC code (or EAN if in europe) which is universal for that product. For example all products on Amazon have a UPC code which is how they organize different sellers for the same product

VERSUS a SKU or Product ID - which is unique to the shop owner. That is what the shop owner uses to track inventory and prices. The universal UPC plus unique SKU is how amazon determines the product that is sold.

In your last example - you are talking about functioning as a "marketplace" like Amazon.com Amazon lets merchants determine their own prices - **but very important to know the price is ranked as price + shipping cost**. Because some merchants will lower the product price to try and come out on top but then they inflate the shipping cost to make up for it.